# view profiler performance report button disabled in VSTS

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

I am following the below link to configure ASP.net profiler with VSTS web Test.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/01/12/vsts-2010-feature-asp-net-profiler-
integration-with-load-tests.aspx

I have followed all the test but somehow the button is not getting enabled.

Also for troubleshooting I followed the below link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5427169-3402-4acb-98a1-23b417ceaa62/view-profiler-performance-report-button-is-disabled-after-configuring-aspnet-profiler?forum=vstswebtest